# Error getting value of a query string

Tags: php, .htaccess

I removed all files with .php extension on my project folder using this .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php?%1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Now, for example, home/product.php becomes home/product. 
However I have a problem, I have a url with a query string like this - "home/product_details.php?id=$id". I can only access "home/product_details". I want it to be like "home/product_details/$id".

Please how do I do it and how can I get the value of $id?

I would usually do:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

I think I need to adjust something in the .htaccess but I don't know.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you use any php frameworks?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rules :

```
RewriteEngine on
#remove .php exten
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule (.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
#rewrite /file/foobar to /file.php?id=foobar
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/?$ /$1.php?id=$1 [L]
```